# Create php function to retrieve a customers subscription renewal order status in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

PHP function to:

- Get current customer ID
- If customer has subscription proceed
- If EXISTS -> Get latest customer subscription renewal order
- Check status of renewal order (i.e. 'pending payment', 'on-hold', processing, 'complete')
- RETURN status of renewal order

Here's what I have so far:

```
function get_last_customer_renewal_order() {
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if (has_woocommerce_subscription('','','')){
    $subscriptions = wcs_get_users_subscriptions($current_user_id);
    $related_order_ID = array();
    $related_orders = array();
    foreach($subscriptions as $subscription) {
     // The subscription ID
     $related_order_ID[] = $subscription->get_related_orders( 'ids', 'renewal' );
     foreach($related_order_ID as $related_orders) {
         foreach($related_orders as $related_order) {
             $order = wc_get_order( print_r($related_order[0]));             
             echo $order->get_status;
         }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you think we are here to develop your functionality ? We are here to resolve your problems. First do some code and show that to us if anything is wrong that we can help you out.

Comment: Please go read [ask] first of all. This is not a site where you can just drop off your requirement, and expect some eager minions to do the work for you. We want to see _your_ effort first of all, and for you to ask us a specific question about problems with a piece of code you have written.

Comment: Not at all Aki & misrorude, I just thought that someone would have already produced this type of function before. I've put my work so far into the Q above. Just looking for some help :)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
So I've managed to retrieve the renewal ID, with the function below:

```
function get_last_customer_renewal_order() {
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();

    if (has_woocommerce_subscription('','','')){

        $subscriptions = wcs_get_users_subscriptions($current_user_id);
        $related_order_ID = array();
        $related_orders = array();

        foreach($subscriptions as $subscription) {

         // The subscription ID
         $related_order_ID[] = $subscription->get_related_orders( 'ids', 'renewal' );

            foreach($related_order_ID as $related_orders) {

                foreach($related_orders as $related_order) {
                    $order_id = $related_order;

                    if (! $order_id = ""){
                        $the_order_id = $related_order;
                        break 3;
                    }
                    else{
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //$order = wc_get_order($the_order_id);
        $order = new WC_Order( $the_order_id );
        $order_status = $order->get_status();

        //echo $the_order_id, '</br>', $order_status;

        return $order_status;
    }
    else{}
}
```

Comment: that's a very weird check: if (! $order_id = ""){ it assigns order_id to empty?